# Confirm system crontab functionality on Arch

Tags: archlinux, cron

Arch ARM comes with `cronie` cron daemon. However I can't find the system crontab file and running `crontab -l` as root returns `no crontab for root`.

`systemctl is-enabled cronie` reports `enabled`

I have a number of script in the `/etc/cron.period` directories but suspect they might not get executed. For example I have a script in `cron.weekly` that hasn't run for 9 days. It can be executed manually and has these file flags:

```
-rwxr--r--  1 root root 1,7K 24 apr 23.55 task1.cron*
```

How can I check that there's a schedule for the `/etc/cron.period` directories and where do I find the system crontab?

There's `/etc/anacrontab` but I'm not sure if it's used by the system. There's no `/etc/crontab`.

**update:** `journalctl -u cronie` reports `No journal files were found.`, but I have the fillowing in `/var/log/everything.log`:

```
May 18 00:01:01 pi CROND[30893]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
May 18 00:01:01 pi anacron[30898]: Anacron started on 2013-05-18
May 18 00:01:01 pi anacron[30898]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 6 min.
May 18 00:01:01 pi anacron[30898]: Will run job `ron.weekly' in 26 min.
May 18 00:01:01 pi anacron[30898]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
May 18 00:07:01 pi anacron[30898]: Job `cron.daily' started
May 18 00:08:00 pi anacron[30898]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
May 18 00:27:01 pi anacron[30898]: Job `ron.weekly' started
May 18 00:27:01 pi anacron[30898]: Job `ron.weekly' terminated
May 18 00:27:01 pi anacron[30898]: Normal exit (2 jobs run)
May 18 01:01:01 pi CROND[32633]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
May 18 02:01:01 pi CROND[32645]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
May 18 03:01:01 pi CROND[32653]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
```

`anacron` appears to be active but the weekly job seems to be missing the character c at the beginning of its name. I wonder if could have anything to do with weekly scripts not running.

**update 2:** I restored (an unedited) `/etc/anacrontab`:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
RANDOM_DELAY=45
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=3-22

#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1       5       cron.daily              nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7       25      cron.weekly             nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45     cron.monthly            nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

I then ran `anacron -T` to test `/etc/anacrontab` validity, following the anacron man page. It reported no errors.

I then tried `anacron -n -d` and got this:

```
Anacron started on 2013-05-18
Checking against 25 with 30
Normal exit (0 jobs run)
```

That seems odd. I had expected to run the three jobs (cron.daily, cron.weekly, cron.monthly). `-n` is supposed to run jobs immediately but that seems not to happen.

**update 3:** I noticed that `run-parts --test` doesn't list scripts that have extensions. I also needed to add `-f` to `anacron` to ignore timestamps in order to force execution of jobs.

**update final:** `/etc/anacrontab` is indeed the system crontab as @Lekensteyn indicated. The reason some of my scripts were not running was because those script names contained dots (e.g. task1.cron) which is not accepted by `run-parts`, as documented in its man page:

> If neither the --lsbsysinit option nor the --regex option is given then the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters, ASCII digits, ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens.

I can now consistently force jobs to run by executing `anacron -dfn cron.weekly` or some other job name, or all jobs if the job name is omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to test whether a cron job has run, check your syslog. On Arch Linux with cronie, this can be done with `journalctl -u cronie`.

`cronie`s daemon is called `crond`. From its manual page:

> Cron checks these files and directories:
>
> /etc/crontab
>
> > system crontab. Nowadays the file is empty by default. Originally it was
> >     usually used to run daily, weekly, monthly jobs. By default these jobs are
> >     **now run through anacron which reads /etc/anacrontab** configuration file. See
> >     anacrontab(5) for more details.
>
> /etc/cron.d/
>
> > directory that contains system cronjobs stored for different users.

The file `/etc/anacrontab` is indeed used to run the tasks:

```
#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1       5       cron.daily              nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7       25      cron.weekly             nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45     cron.monthly            nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

As for `/etc/cron.hourly`, the file `/etc/cron.d/0hourly` configures that:

```
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
```

`crontab -l` only lists user crons located in `/var/spool/cron/`, not the ones in `/etc/`.

Comment: Thank you for this. It clarifies and confirms some things. For some reason `weekly` (at least) scripts are not run even though anacron shows activity. I've updated my question with more information.

Comment: Can you ensure that your system is up-to-date and that the `anacrontab` file is not corrupted? My Arch Linux installation on the Pi shows the name correctly.

Comment: I had edited `anacrontab`and had accidentally deleted the c, changing the job-identifier. The command was unchanged though. I've now restored it from backup. Could I speed up `weekly` by setting the period to 1?

Comment: seron, weekly means every seven days. If you change it to one, then you have effectively a daily job. If you want to test your cron, why not move it to `/etc/cron.hourly` or even create a `crontab` entry that executes in a minute?

Comment: I see you point. My idea is to quicker verify that `anacron` does run its job commands by increasing the job frequency. It seems that daily is the shortest frequency available in anacrontab.